# How to correctly outprint this array in java?

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to take an input from the user for the array size and then ask the user for the array contents. This part seems to work fine but the outprint isn't working. It out prints 0's for the marks. Thanks for any help provided.

```
public static void getExamMarks()
{
    int x,mark;
    System.out.println("Please enter the number of exam marks: ");
    x=Keyboard.readInt();

    int javastudents[]=new int[x];
    for (int i=0;i<javastudents.length;i++)
    {
        System.out.println("Please enter an intiger for the mark: ");
        mark=Keyboard.readInt();
    }
    printArray(javastudents);
}
public static void printArray(int [] javastudents)
{
    for (int i=0;i<javastudents.length;i++)
    {
        System.out.println(javastudents[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is printArray printing? Which is that output that you want?

Comment: @Narkha it should outprint the marks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are reading the value from the keyboard into the `mark` variable, but you are not using the `mark` variable anymore afterwards. At the same time, you are not storing anything into your `javastudents` array, so all array elements remain at their initial value of `0`. Hence, when printing the array later, you get all `0`'s.

You need to store the read value into your array, like

```
...
mark = Keyboard.readInt();
javastudents[i] = mark;
...
```

In fact, you do not need the `mark` variable at all and you can do

```
...
javastudents[i] = Keyboard.readInt();
...
```